# why no constructor is called?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have written a test class to but i'm failing to understanding whats happening!.

Is the Move/copy being elided? if so how could it be updated with the new value. i'm definitely missing something.

here is the test case(Please dont consider the usefulness)

```
#include<iostream>

struct Test
{
    int a;  
    Test(){a = 10;std::cout<<"def\n";}
    Test(int a){this->a = a;std::cout<<"unary\n";}
    Test(const Test& a){this->a = a.a; std::cout<<"copy\n";}
    Test(Test&& a){this->a = a.a; std::cout<<"Move\n";}
    Test& operator=(const Test& a){this->a = a.a;std::cout<<"op=\n";}
    Test& operator=(Test&& a){this->a = a.a;std::cout<<"Move=\n";}
    void display(){std::cout << "Display ";}
};   


Test gi(Test a)
{
    std::cout<<a.a<<"&\n";
    return a;
}

int main()
{
    //Test a = 99;
    //Test();
/*Line MST*/    Test b = Test(102);//gi(a);  
    std::cout<<b.a<<'\n';

return 0;
}
```

here line MST is what i dont understand. if i initialize it with a temporary `Test` object should it not call Move constructor(or atleast the copy)?

the output is :

```
unary
102
```

similar output with this line

```
 Test b = gi(Test(103));
```

here Move/copy is not happening during call to gi()?

but this is as i expect

```
Test a = 99;
Test b = gi(a);
```

what am i missing here?

Comment: As far as I know, `Test b = Test(102);` is explicitly considered a standard way of initializing an object, not a creation of temporary and subsequent copy/move construction. You should also try what happens when you reduce or turn off the compiler optimizations. The copy elision on return usually only comes into effect with compiler optimizations, so both your `gi()` call examples should give use a copy and/or move constructor.

Comment: @Piotr99 actually Test(102); should create a unnamed temporary that gets copied/Moved via constructors is what i expected. further more i compiled with default optimization(`g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp`).

Comment: no, that was my point: `Test var = Test(123);` is an initialization, which the compiler can identify easily as such. It qualifies for copy/move elision according to C++11 standard document 12.8, subsection 31: "when a temporary class object that has not been bound to a reference (12.2) would be copied/moved to a class object with the same cv-unqualified type, the copy/move operation can be omitted by constructing the temporary object directly into the target of the omitted copy/move". To my knowledge, compilers nowadays rarely ever create a temporary for this.

Comment: You might want to experiment with the gcc compiler switch `-fno-elide-constructors`, which prevents exactly this behaviour.

Comment: @Piotr99 **"the copy/move operation can be omitted by constructing the temporary object directly into the target of the omitted copy/move"**. this is what is most interesting for me. never realized this is so powerful. and yes you are completely right compilers know better:) thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is the Move/copy being elided? if so how could it be updated with the new value

Yes, the copy is being elided per § 12.8/31 of the C++11 Standard. It is completely up to the compiler when and whether to perform this optimization, and you should not have expectations on it being or not being performed (even if the copy constructor or move constructor has side effects).

Comment: will i be guaranteed that my object `b` will be in the state that i expect it to be? and is it copy being elided or move?:)

Comment: @Koushik: If the state of your object `b` is somehow influenced by the fact that a copy constructor or move constructor is invoked rather than not, then you won't know for sure. But in fact copy and move constructors should be designed in a way that does not make that happen. In your case, move constructor and copy constructor are written properly, so yes, you are guaranteed that `b` will be in the state you expect it to be

Comment: @Koushik: Concerning the second question, in your case you have a viable move constructor, so if the compiler did not perform copy elision, the move constructor would be invoked (it's called "copy elision" in the Standard, but that includes eliding calls to the move constructor). So to answer your question: it's the move being elided

Comment: perhaps one should add that copy (and move) elison is not allowed if the copy (move) constructor are `=delete`: even if they would be elided, they must be possible.

Comment: @Walter: Not just if the are deleted, but also if they are inaccessible (e.g. `private`)